# How correctly to process an arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

There are two arrays:

```
$arr1 = ['word', 'tech', 'care', 'kek', 'lol', 'wild', 'regex'];
$arr2 = ['ord', 'ek', 'ol', 'ld', 'gex', 'ss'];
```

The number of elements in the second array is less than or equal to the first array.

Sort out the first array and the second array, if the elements of the second array are contained at the end of the elements of the first array, sort the array in this form:

```
Array
(
    [0] => w_ord
    [1] => tech
    [2] => care
    [3] => k_ek
    [4] => l_ol
    [5] => wi_ld
    [6] => re_gex
)
```

Important: the elements of the second array are never repeated, and can go in any order. If in the second element there is no end of the element of the first array, then set the value of the element of the first array.

I do this:

```
foreach($arr2 as $val) {
    $strrepl[$val] = "_".$val;
}

foreach($arr1 as $key => $val) {
    $arr3[$key] = str_replace(array_keys($strrepl), $strrepl, $val);
}

print_r($arr3);
```

But I'm not sure that this is the right approach, what will you advise?

Comment: Your `str_replace()` will replace any occurrence and not just the end of the string.

Comment: @NigelRen, i understand, but I can not think up an alternative solution with checks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmm, let's see ... purely functional 'cause you know :D

```
function ends($str) {
  return function($suffix) use($str) {
    return mb_strlen($str) >= mb_strlen($suffix)
      && mb_substr($str, mb_strlen($suffix) * -1) === $suffix;
  };
}

$result = array_map(function($item) use($arr2) {
  $filter = ends($item);
  $suffixes = array_filter($arr2, $filter);

  if (empty($suffixes)) {
    return $item;
  }
  // This only cares about the very first match, but
  // is easily adaptable to handle all of them
  $suffix = reset($suffixes);

  return mb_substr($item, 0, mb_strlen($suffix) * -1) . "_{$suffix}";
}, $arr1);
```

Comment: what the kind of hard art? :D

Comment: Not hard, just functional programming - genuine, beautiful and a tad bit esoteric.

Comment: And yet your decision suits me most, very elegant approach, thank you!

Comment: That's only slightly confusing by the verbose syntax of function declare and call and array_map in PHP.

Comment: @JesúsFranco You're right, it is verbose. Though nothing stops you from using something more streamlined like Laravel's `collection` class.

Answer (score 5):

Surprisingly, this one was quite fun to execute.
Since you went very specific on **end** of the element, I decided to use RegEx for that.

Here is my approach:

```
$arr1 = ['word', 'tech', 'care', 'kek', 'lol', 'wild', 'regex'];
$arr2 = ['ord', 'ek', 'ol', 'ld', 'gex', 'ss'];

foreach ($arr2 as $find) {
   foreach ($arr1 as $key => $element) {
        $arr1[$key] = preg_replace('/' . $find . '$/', '_' . $find, $element);
    }
}
```

For every element of the second array (since they are not repeated), I go through every element of the first array and check if the value can be found at the end of the element of the second array using the `$` anchor from RegEx which forces it to look it from the end of the string.

This way the $arr1 will have exactly what you expect.

[Edit]
Following the scape suggestion from @aefxx and improving variable names.

Comment: No problem mate. Please keep in mind a concept we call Self Documenting Code.
It's usually when you declare the variables not by short names but by meaning what they are supposed to contain.

It is extremely helpful if you have to look at your code again someday in the (not so near) future. :)

Comment: @RafaelBoszko Please update your code to properly escape the `$value` before dumping it into a regex. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php

Comment: I agree, it looks HORRIBLE.
Thanks aefxx.

Comment: Oh and besides your answer might do more than anticipated, try: `$arr1 = ['mom']; $arr2 = ['dad', 'om', 'm'];`

Comment: Good point. Touche.
Cant think on how to overcome that now xD

Answer (score 4):

You can use preg_grep which is regex on arrays.
This code will also make sure it can output more than one matching word from $arr1.

```
$arr1 = ['word', 'chord', 'tech', 'care', 'kek', 'lol', 'wild', 'regex'];
$arr2 = ['ord', 'ek', 'ol', 'ld', 'gex', 'ss'];

$keys=[];
foreach($arr2 as $val){
    $matches = preg_grep("/.+" . preg_quote($val) . "/", $arr1);
    $keys = array_merge($keys, array_keys($matches)); // save keys of matched words
    foreach($matches as $key => $m) $new[$val][] = str_replace($val, "_$val", $arr1[$key]);
}
$new['unmatched'] = array_diff_key($arr1, array_flip($keys)); // add unmatched words
var_dump($new);
```

Output:

```
array(6) {
  ["ord"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "w_ord"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "ch_ord"
  }
  ["ek"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "k_ek"
  }
  ["ol"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "l_ol"
  }
  ["ld"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "wi_ld"
  }
  ["gex"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "re_gex"
  }
  ["unmatched"]=>
  array(2) {
    [2]=>
    string(4) "tech"
    [3]=>
    string(4) "care"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/gfUea

Comment: Woooow, this is a very interesting option, especially considering several endings

Comment: Thanks! I just noticed that my output does not include the ones that do not match. Do you need them there? `tech care`

Answer (score 3):

You can try this.I think it is easy to understand :

```
$arr1=['word','tech','care','kek','lol','wild','regex'];
$arr2=['ord','ek','ol','ld','gex','ss'];

foreach($arr1 as $key=>$fullword){
    foreach($arr2 as $substr){
        $arr1[$key]=preg_replace('/' . $substr . '$/', '_' . $substr, $fullword,-1,$count);
        if($count) break;
    }
}
```

i go throught the array of fullword and as soon as i find a match i stop the search.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach can be to create complex regex beforehand (using [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and [`preg_quote`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) for safety) and use it for replacement inside [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) callback:

```
$arr1 = ['word', 'tech', 'care', 'kek', 'lol', 'wild', 'regex'];
$arr2 = ['ord', 'ek', 'ol', 'ld', 'gex', 'ss'];

$regex = '/(' . implode('|', array_map('preg_quote', $arr2)) . ')$/';

$result = array_map(function ($word) use ($regex) {
    return preg_replace($regex, '_$1', $word);
}, $arr1);
```

Here is [the demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aaec0abfc84ff11a1af2c85ee2b08626f502bb1f).